# When using Gnuplot, how can the equation of a line be printed in the line title?

Tags: regression, gnuplot

I have used Gnuplot to plot my data, along with a linear regression line. Currently, the 'title' of this line, which has its equation calculated by Gnuplot, is just "f(x)". However, I would like the title to be the equation of the regression line, e.g. "y=mx+c".

I can do this manually by reading off 'm' and 'c' from the plotting info output, then re-plot with the new title. I would like this process to be automated, and was wondering if this can be done, and how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With a data file `Data.csv`:

```
0   0.00000
1   1.00000
2   1.41421
3   1.73205
4   2.00000
5   2.23607
```

you can do a linear fitting with:

```
f(x) = a*x + b

fit f(x) 'Data.csv' u 1:2 via a, b
```

You can use what I think is called a macro in gnuplot to set the title in the legend of you identified function `f(x)` with

```
title_f(a,b) = sprintf('f(x) = %.2fx + %.2f', a, b)
```

Now in order to plot the data with the regression function `f(x)` simply do:

```
plot "Data.csv" u 1:2 w l, f(x) t title_f(a,b)
```

You should end up with this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [Correlation coefficient on gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957456/correlation-coefficient-on-gnuplot/18041956#18041956) :

Another, perhaps slightly shorter way than Woltan's of doing the same thing may be:

```
# This command will analyze your data and set STATS_* variables. See help stats
stats Data.csv
f(x) = STATS_slope * x + STATS_intercept
plot f(x) title sprintf("y=%.2fx+%.2f", STATS_slope, STATS_intercept)
```

Comment: Just an FYI, the `stats` command cannot analyze your data when in `timedata mode, via the `xdata time`.