# Correlation coefficient on gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, regression, correlation

I want to plot data using fit function : `function f(x) = a+b*x**2`. After ploting i have this result:

```
correlation matrix of the fit parameters:

               m      n      
m               1.000 
n              -0.935  1.000
```

My question is : how can i found a correlation coefficient on gnuplot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to calculate the [correlation coefficient as defined on this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CorrelationCoefficient.html), you are out of luck using gnuplot as explained in this [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/bX-sKHJaTEg).

There are lots of other tools for calculating correlation coefficients, e.g. [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893657/how-do-i-calculate-r-squared-using-python-and-numpy).

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `stats` command in **gnuplot**, which has syntax similar to the `plot` command:

`stats "file.dat" using 2:(f($2)) name "A"`

The correlation coefficient will be stored in the `A_correlation`     variable. (With no name specification, it would be `STATS_correlation`.) You can use it subsequently to plot your data or just print on the screen using the `set label` command:

`set label 1 sprintf("r = %4.2f",A_correlation)  at graph 0.1, graph 0.85`

You can find more about the `stats` command in [gnuplot documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Although there is no direct solution to this problem, a workaround is possible. I'll illustrate it using python/numpy. First, the part of the gnuplot script that generates the fit and connects with a python script:

```
    file = "my_data.tsv"
    f(x)=a+b*(x)
    fit f(x) file using 2:3 via a,b
    r = system(sprintf("python correlation.py %s",file)) 
    ti = sprintf("y = %.2f + %.2fx (r = %s)", a, b, r)
    plot \
      file using 2:3 notitle,\
      f(x) title ti
```

This runs correlation.py to retrieve the correlation 'r' in string format. It uses 'r' to generate a title for the fit line. Then, correlation.py:

```
    from numpy import genfromtxt
    from numpy import corrcoef
    import sys
    data = genfromtxt(sys.argv[1], delimiter='\t')
    r = corrcoef(data[1:,1],data[1:,2])[0,1]
    print("%.3f" % r).lstrip('0')
```

Here, the first row is assumed to be a header row. Furthermore, the columns to calculate the correlation for are now hardcoded to nr. 1 and 2. Of course, both settings can be changed and turned into arguments as well.

The resulting title of the fit line is (for a personal example):

```
y = 2.15 + 1.58x (r = .592)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are probably using fit function you can first refer to this [link](http://computingnote.blogspot.com/2013/04/calculating-r2-with-gnuplot.html) to arrive at R2 values. 
The link uses certain existing variables like FIT_WSSR, FIT_NDF to calculate R2 value.
The code for R2 is stated as:

```
SST = FIT_WSSR/(FIT_NDF+1)
SSE=FIT_WSSR/(FIT_NDF)
SSR=SST-SSE
R2=SSR/SST
```

The next step would be to show the R^2 values on the graph. Which can be achieved using the code :

`set label 1 sprintf("r = %f",R2)  at graph 0.7, graph 0.7`

Comment: I think you’ve abbreviated the blog post too much. The SST calculation needs to happen after a special fit (`fit m 'your data file' using 1:2 via m`, to get the mean value), not after the regular fit as the other assignments. (Also, I think the SSE calculation needs to divide by `FIT_NDF + 2` instead of `FIT_NDF`, but that bug is present in the blog post as well.)

Comment: Primarily, R2 is generally used as qualitative more than a quantitative tool. An R2 of 0.88 is practically similar to 0.82 for many applications.  But I would love to learn more about this FIT_NDF + 2 logic as it better to be accurate. Also can you please explain this special fit vs general fit terminology. Further, Just to be clear, this is the R*2 value for the fit right. Because this google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/bX-sKHJaTEg) claims we cannot calculate R*2 using gnuplot.